# Shopify cart change.js bad request

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, shopify

I have ReCharge app setup, also have a selling plan set up through it. I followed Shopify's documentation here:
https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/pricing-payments/purchase-options/support-purchase-options#the-selling-plan-selector

I have a select element which should update the selling plan for the item in my cart, however, I'm not sure why the script shopify provided is not working. I'm getting "400 (Bad Request)" when selecting options.

````
                        {% if item.variant.selling_plan_allocations.size > 0 %}
                        <label for="selling-plan-selector-{{ item.id }}">Choose a plan:</label>
                        <select name="selling-plan" data-line="{{ forloop.index }}" data-quantity="{{ item.quantity }}">
                        <option value="">One-time purchase</option>

                        {% for selling_plan_allocation in item.variant.selling_plan_allocations %}
                          <option
                            value="{{ selling_plan_allocation.selling_plan.id }}"
                            {% if item.selling_plan_allocation.selling_plan.id == selling_plan_allocation.selling_plan.id %}selected="selected"{% endif %}
                          >
                            {{ selling_plan_allocation.selling_plan.name }}
                          </option>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </select>

                      {% endif %}```
````

and here's the script using cart/change.js

```
<script>
  document.querySelectorAll('[name="selling-plan"]').forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      console.log('Select Element InnerHTML:', e.target.innerHTML);
      console.log('Selected Selling Plan ID:', e.target.value);
      let data = {
        'line': e.target.dataset.line,
        'quantity': e.target.dataset.quantity,
        'id': e.target.value
      };
  
      console.log('Sending data:', JSON.stringify(data)); // Check the data object again
  

      // Log the data object that will be sent in the request
      console.log('Sending data:', JSON.stringify(data));

      fetch('/cart/change.js', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
      .then(response => {
        // Log the response status and status text
        console.log('Response Status:', response.status);
        console.log('Response Status Text:', response.statusText);

        return response.json();
      })
      .then(responseData => {
        // Log the full response data
        console.log('Response Data:', responseData);

        // Refresh page, or re-render cart
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

I even had all those console.logs to check the values, but the ID is blank.